# Input file accept="image/*" capture="camera" disable browsing on mobile device

Tags: android, html

I have this html line to allow for file uploads. The issue now when I tried on android it allows me to browser from my phone. I want to totally disabled any browsing but just directly to the camera. I have put the capture="camera" it still gives me the option to browse. The page is a php page.

```
<form class="form-horizontal" action="ag1.php" method="post" name="form1" id=form1 enctype="multipart/form-data" onSubmit="return validateForm();">

<input type='file' id="sImage" name="sImage" accept="image/*" capture="camera">
```

Comment: did you found any solution ?

Answer (score 2):

Setting `capture="environment"` for back camera and `capture="user"` for front camera will force the camera to be displayed. So your code should look like this.

```
<input type='file' id="sImage" name="sImage" accept="image/*" capture="environment">
```

Let me know if this works.

Comment: is there any way to disable camera option while file selecting

Comment: @DivyeshKanzariya I want to know the same thing. did you figure out if this is possible?

Comment: @DivyeshKanzariya i'd like to know too

Comment: @LorisTujiba try capture="filesystem" might be work